# How to completely uninstall/remove cygwin from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, cygwin

How can I completely uninstall/remove cygwin? I don't think it is as simple as deleting C:\cygwin. Maybe alter registry?

Comment: The most recent information is found at its source, always; https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.setup.uninstall-all

Answer (score 66):

The developers give fairly [detailed instructions](http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.setup.uninstall-all) on how to remove the software:

> **How do I uninstall all of Cygwin?**
>
> Setup has no automatic uninstall facility. The recommended method to
>   remove all of Cygwin is as follows:
>
> 1. If you have any Cygwin services running, remove by repeating the instructions in
>      http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.setup.uninstall-service for all
>      services that you installed. Common services that might have been
>      installed are `sshd, cron, cygserver, inetd, apache, postgresql,` and
>      so on.
> 2. Stop the X11 server if it is running, and terminate any Cygwin programs that might be running in the background. Exit the command
>      prompt and ensure that no Cygwin processes remain. Note: If you want
>      to save your mount points for a later reinstall, first save the output
>      of `mount -m` as described at
>      http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html#mount.
> 3. Delete the Cygwin root folder and all subfolders. If you get an error that an object is in use, then ensure that you've stopped all
>      services and closed all Cygwin programs. If you get a 'Permission
>      Denied' error then you will need to modify the permissions and/or
>      ownership of the files or folders that are causing the error. For
>      example, sometimes files used by system services end up owned by the
>      SYSTEM account and not writable by regular users.
>
>    The quickest way to delete the entire tree if you run into this problem is to change the ownership of all files and folders to your
>      account. To do this in Windows Explorer, right click on the root
>      Cygwin folder, choose Properties, then the Security tab. If you are
>      using Windows XP Home or Simple File Sharing, you will need to boot
>      into Safe Mode to access the Security tab. Select Advanced, then go to
>      the Owner tab and make sure your account is listed as the owner.
>      Select the 'Replace owner on subcontainers and objects' checkbox and
>      press Ok. After Explorer applies the changes you should be able to
>      delete the entire tree in one operation. Note that you can also
>      achieve this in Cygwin by typing `chown -R user /` or by using other
>      tools such as `CACLS.EXE`.
> 4. Delete the Cygwin shortcuts on the Desktop and Start Menu, and anything left by setup.exe in the download directory. However, if you
>      plan to reinstall Cygwin it's a good idea to keep your `setup.exe`
>      download directory since you can reinstall the packages left in its
>      cache without redownloading them.
> 5. If you added Cygwin to your system path, you should remove it unless you plan to reinstall Cygwin to the same location. Similarly,
>      if you set your CYGWIN environment variable system-wide and don't plan
>      to reinstall, you should remove it.
> 6. Finally, if you want to be thorough you can delete the registry tree `Software\Cygwin` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and/or
>      `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. However, if you followed the directions above you
>      will have already removed everything important. Typically only the
>      installation directory has been stored in the registry at all.

Comment: I originally found these instructions at the source that John T linked to and tried them on Windows 7. They didn't work for me. Has anyone gotten them to work on Windows 7? I wasn't able to delete the `C:\Cygwin` directory, even after booting into safe mode with a command prompt.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Every couple of years I get to a point where I think cygwin might be useful and that it can't be as useless as I remember it (today I wanted to do a bit of Lisp hacking). Then after installing it and wasting about two hours because nothing works and there is no documentation I get this horrible feeling of deja vu and remember that it is virus-like in its difficulty to remove from your machine. Ubuntu under VMWARE seems like a much better option.

Comment: I had to do more than just change the owner in order to delete, I also had to change the permissions to be more permissive (basically let everyone have full access). This is the permissions tab next to the owner tab. Cygwin: not even once.

Comment: The command you indicate (`chown -R user /`) is NOT the equivalent of changing ownership of the Cygwin folder. It will modify the ownership of ALL files on the filesystem.

Comment: @piwi, from within a cygwin shell, the `/` folder is the root of the cygwin folder, not the windows system volume "root".  That command will not modify ownership of all files on the windows system filesystem.

Answer (score 48):

Actually it was rather... easy.
Just do this...

```
takeown /f C:\cygwin /r /d y
icacls c:\cygwin /t /grant everyone:F
del c:\cygwin
```

then just right click delete it . it'll be gone.

Comment: My two cents:
- These commands have to be executed with administrative privileges ("Run as Administrator").
- If some files cannot be deleted, use a tool like Unlocker to get rid of them.
- At the end use a Registry cleaner tool (e.g. CCleaner) to remove residual Registry entries.

Comment: Also C:\cygwin64 for the 64-bit version

Comment: `del` didn't work for me, I used `Remove-Item "C:\cygwin64" -Recurse -Force`

Comment: then in the registry I deleted Cygwin  in `Software\Cygwin under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and/or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` (as mentioned above).

Comment: @daka most likely you're running a powershell session

Comment: C:\>`rmdir /s /q cygwin64` - you have to do that because `del` is just for files, cf. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54637875/6505499) ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20230311201957/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607612/equivalent-of-rm-and-mv-in-windows-cmd/54637875#54637875)). Or, still from the `CMD` prompt (as long as you have `PowerShell`), `powershell -c Remove-Item "C:\cygwin64" -Recurse -Force`.

Comment: I had a german installation which didn't understand `/d y` but `/d j`and the folder was `C:\cygwin64`. So: `takeown /f c:cygwin64 /r /d j`.

Answer (score 17):

Follow the below steps.

1. `C:\>takeown /r /d y /f cygwin`
2. `C:\>icacls cygwin /t /grant Everyone:F`
3. `C:\cygwin\bin>.\cygrunsrv.exe -E sshd`
4. `C:\cygwin\bin>.\cygrunsrv.exe -R sshd`

Then delete the folder `c:\cygwin` and all its sub-folders. This approach worked for me.

*Be aware that windows commands like takeown are depending on the locale, i.e. option `/d y` works only in english systems. In german system one needs to use `/d j` to work (without hint in the english help, *facepalm* microsoft)*

Comment: Also only `icacls cygwin /t /grant Jeder:F` worked for me on my german system

Answer (score 6):

I did this in Win 7 after trying everything possible from within Win 7 (note... I have been able to disable rootkits easier than delete CygWin!!)

1. `C:\>takeown /r /d y /f cygwin`

   Only worked for one folder ('var' I think)
2. `C:\>icacls cygwin /t /grant Everyone:F`

   worked
3. `C:\>takeown /r /d y /f cygwin`

   repeating this command worked after the above (second) command!!
4. `C:\cygwin\bin>.\cygrunsrv.exe -E sshd`

   gave access denied
5. `C:\cygwin\bin>.\cygrunsrv.exe -R sshd`

gave access denied

BUT I then went to Windows explorer and deleted (recycled) the C:\Cygwin folder and it worked. Gone completely.

Thanks to the above post!
Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [Luigi's answer](https://superuser.com/a/788659/743116),

> `icacls c:\cygwin /t /grant everyone:F`

In localized Windows there's no security group with name "everyone", you should replace a group name by a correspondent SID:

`icacls cygwin /t /grant "*S-1-1-0":F`

More SIDs are [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems).

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble in deleting Cygwin folder and I have traversed the entire directory structure and deleted each sub-folder. This is really painful, but no other choice.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see it mentioned on here but if anyone still can't remove the C:\cygwin folder because it is in use, check for the service 'Server' on your computer. It's not a part of Cygwin, but I saw that it is used for named-pipe sharing, and I was able to delete the Cygwin folder when I stopped it.

Just FYI

Answer (score 1):

Launch the Cygwin installer and goto to package viewer and select view as a category and install type as uninstall ... Done.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. This uninstalls only packages not the whole of cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

Well, none of that worked, so here's what I did:

1. Set owner to whatever user you are, as described above.
2. Delete all users from folder permissions in Security-Edit.
3. Re-add your user and set full control permissions.
4. Go to Advanced and select both checkboxes at the bottom (Include ineritable permissions..., Replace all child object permissions..., blahblahblah).
5. Apply the changes.
6. Simply delete the folder. Should work.

Comment: Can you please format your question.  It would make a helpful question that is extremely hard to read into a question that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this guide

https://cygwin.fandom.com/wiki/Uninstalling_Cygwin

and worked fine