# "net start service" and "sc start". What is the difference?

Tags: windows, command-line

Services can be stopped and started using two commands in Command Prompt Shell.

1. net start service "some service"
2. sc start "some service"

what is the difference between these commands?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

In Windows NT, both commands access the same Service Manager. The difference is mainly in the user-visible part:

- `net` is older – from the days of MS-DOS and OS/2, in fact.

  `sc` only appeared with Windows NT *(not sure which version)*.
- `net` can only start, stop and pause services.

  `sc` has more advanced controls, can query state, create and delete services, change their configuration and security: `sc config beep start= demand`
- `net` only works locally.

  `sc` can be used over the network: `sc \\snow start rpcapd`
- `net` accepts display names: `net start "Windows Firewall"`

  `sc` always requires a service name: `sc start SharedAccess`

Answer (score 99):

Grawity's answer is certainly helpful, but I found a fundamental difference between these commands detailed on http://cbfive.com/command-line-service-management-net-v-sc/ .  In particular, this page notes that these two commands differ in their *timing*: **"net" is synchronous and "sc" is asynchronous.**

> **SC sends the control to the service and then returns to the command
> prompt.**  This typically results in SC START returning the service in a
> state of START_PENDING.  **NET START will wait for the service it is
> starting to come to a fully started state before it returns** control at
> the command prompt.
>
> ...
>
> [L]ike SC START, **SC STOP does not wait for the service to come to a stop**
> and will there for often return STOP_PENDING for many service stop
> operations.  **NET STOP on the other hand will wait on the service to stop**
> before it returns to the command prompt.
>
> ...
>
> **NET and SC have different ideas of what they consider to be
> success conditions.**  The question SC asks to determine if it was
> successful is, “Did I successfully send a stop control to the
> service?”  If it did, regardless of whether the service stopped, then
> I satisfied the successful condition.  NET asks the question, “Did the
> service I attempted to stop, return that it stopped successfully?”  If
> it did, then it satisfied the condition.  If it didn’t, no matter what
> the reason, then NET fails the successful condition

Comment: An interesting detail, this one. Could be useful to know for scripting cases (%ERRORLEVEL% variable). Thanks.

Comment: this answer is super helpful for me as I'm experiencing intermittent scripting errors trying to clean the service directory after stopping it since it's not fully stopped.

Comment: i want to use "sc config", is that asynchronous too? is there a way for a batch file to wait until the task is actually completed?

Comment: `sc \\server query service_name` is the command to get the current status.  Your script can then loop until it gets what it wants.

Answer (score 4):

For what its worth, I've found sc start/stop to be more reliable than net start/stop. 
Sometimes net start/stop caused the service to be stuck in a Starting/Stopping state whereas this has never occurred to me yet with sc start/stop. The net start/stop symptom tends to occur more often if the service was killed (via taskkill), e.g. attempting to start the service with net start after taskkill.

Answer (score 3):

Left to say that if the OnStart() routine of a service takes too long, `NET START` sends a stop command to the service and returns the following error:

> The ServiceName service is starting........
>
> The ServiceName service could not be started.
>
> The service did not report an error.
>
> More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3534.

This happens although the service has been started and stopped successfully !!

I also found this post here, that might be interesting:
[Service could not be started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947106/the-service-could-not-be-started-but-does-start-c-sharp)